# Laravel : Is there a way to get the guard of auth middleware in Login Controller?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to set the guard in routes and get them into Laravel's built in `LoginController`.

```php
//routes/web.php

Route::get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login')->middleware('guest:dashboard');
Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login')->middleware('guest:dashboard');
Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');
Route::get('/', 'DashboardController@index')->name('index')->middleware('auth:dashboard');
```

I don't want to return default guard. Just specify `middleware('auth:{guard-name}')` and call it like :

```php
//LoginController
  protected function guard($guard)
    {

        return Auth::guard('$guard');
    }
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Auth has this function to check guard. you can do it by Auth::checkguard(); which will return the respective guard of logged in user. If nothing found, you can make it 'guest'.

Comment: Try `Route::current()->parameter('guard')`